# What type of FHIR resource records an intervention

Tags: hapi, hl7-fhir

The FHIR specification has a number of resources:

http://hl7.org/fhir/2018May/resourcelist.html

Suppose a doctor:

- recommended bedrest for a patient or:
- recommended daily exercise

how would these things be recorded in FHIR (which resource type)?
I don't see 'PatientOrder', 'PatientRecommendation', 'PatientIntervention', etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your choices are CarePlan or ServiceRequest.

*Note FHIR versioning: You should look at either http://hl7.org/fhir (for the current official release - STU3) or http://build.fhir.org (for the draft of the next release - R4). The 2018May was a frozen snapshot for ballot but won't be supported by any implementations.*

Comment: It seems like ServiceRequest is not quite right (since no service is being requested). CarePlan.activity.detail.code looks like the right place, but dang... that's nested pretty deep in there. I hope doctors aren't filling these out. :-/

Comment: Or ... CarePlan.activity.detail.code.coding.code="<bedrest code>"

Comment: Technically "bed rest" and "exercise" are both types of procedures - and ServiceRequest is the mechanism for formally ordering both.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks